# htaccess and multiple domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Scenario: I'm directing multiple domains at the same IP/machine, and delivering content that is dependent on the requesting/origin domain. I'm not using name based v-hosts because I need to keep the code-base consolidated, among other miscellaneous reasons. I also need to generate sitemaps for these sites, and maintain them separately. My dilemma is that I'm trying to use htaccess to redirect all *sitemap.xml and *site_index.xml requests to a sub-folder which includes the requesting domain name in it, for example:

http://somedomain.com/sitemap.xml needs to point to a local directory of /var/www/html/sites/somedomain.com/sitemap.xml

or http://someotherdomain.com/sitemap.xml needs to retrieve /var/www/html/sites/someotherdomain.com/sitemap.xml

This also must occur without altering the address within the address bar, or redirecting search bots, etc.

I've looked into directing all *sitemap.xml requests to a script to retrieve and supply the desired data, but this seems cumbersome and not as elegant as a htaccess directive would be. Thus  far I have produced:

RewriteCond $1 !=sites
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/sitemap.xml$ sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/sitemap.xml [L]

which does not result in an error, nor does it result in the desired effect. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:I was able to use the supplied directives of Jacek, and alter them somewhat to achieve what I was after. This is what I ended up with:

`RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/sitemap.xml [L]`

Comment: Better off on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Chris, posted over there to.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more generic answer to handle multiple websites at once: use a [mapfile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).

First I'd suggest to have the folder named like all the "partners" or "websites" **without** extension.

Create a [mapfile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) where you put all the "partners" or "websites" without extension:

```
RewriteMap mappartners \
  dbm:/web/htdocs/one_for_all/rewriterules/partners.map
```

In the mapfile create simple entries like:

```
somedomain           one_for_all/somedomain
someotherdomain      one_for_all/someotherdomain
someotherotherdomain one_for_all/someotherotherdomain
...
```

Then here you go for the hard part:

```
# Make a RewriteCond that fills "%1" with the name of the partner...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.+(fr|com|net|org|eu)$
# ...make a RewriteRule that does nothing but initialize "partner" variable:
RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=PARTNER:${mappartners:%2|notfound}]
# If empty or "notfound"
RewriteCond %{ENV:PARTNER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:PARTNER} notfound
# "not found" 404 :
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]
```

This way everything is dynamic but it's a little bit more complex.

... and finish with a full rewrite of the destination:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:PARTNER}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f
# File exists => rewrite filename and end rewriterule:
RewriteRule  ^(.+) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:PARTNER}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [QSA,L]
```

--
As a note, I've a bunch a RewriteRules like this and my third framework (which you'll see at my future website in a few days (http://papdevis.fr)) is one of the fastest.

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

that should roughly work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ %1/sitemap.xml [L]
```

where .htaccess in in main folder and someotherdomain.com is subfolder

$1, etc. are regexp catches from RewriteRule and %1-type are catches from RewriteCond

Comment: I took what you posted, and had to alter somewhat to get it working. What I ultimately ended up with is: `RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/sitemap.xml [L]`I'm unsure why I couldn't get the second line to work as it, most of the examples I came across included very similar directives. Anyway, thank you very much!